# Having a thread take the time for an external event to complete

Tags: python, multithreading

Hi i'm working on raspberry pi 4. I'm having trouble finding a consistent solution to having a thread measuring the time it takes for an external event to happen.

```
Thread(name='test', target=self.myFunc).start()

def myFunc(self):
    while True:
        if(self.isPinActive(3)):
            start = time.time()
            while(self.isPinActive(3)):
                time.sleep(1)
            end = time.time()
            finalTime = end - start
            if(finalTime > 1):
                print(finalTime)
        time.sleep(1)
```

This is what i have so far.The solution is consistent every time there is a voltage increase on pin 3 it takes a recording of how long that pin was activate. However this function seems pretty heavy on the CPU taking up about 8-12 % of the CPU power. Is there anything i can do to make the function take up less CPU usage? I'm already using a callback for a different purpose.

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(3, GPIO.RISING, callback=otherFunction)
```

and the GPIO pin does not seem to be able to have two callbacks added to it.

Comment: ***"using a callback for a different purpose"***: I can think of using a chained `callback function`. On `callback` call `timer.stop()` and `otherFunction()`